# Fineuploader possible solution to force header return true if default server will not return following JSON Data

Tags: fine-uploader

Not sure if it's possible to force fineuploader to fire true success upload in anyway. im facing the issue of submitting form to a url "http://119.29.222.368:8991/upload"(sample ip due to P&C) where it will return only Status : "OK" without Success : true.

Following is my code, pretty sure that it successfully submitted, but my UI will get error due to the API is not returning the value success.

```
var uploader = new qq.FineUploader({
        element: document.getElementById("uploader"),
        cors: {
            allowXdr: 'true',
            expected:'true'
        },
        request: {
            method:'POST',
            // endpoint: '/upload',
            endpoint: 'http://119.29.222.368:8991/upload',
            forceMultipart:'true',
            inputName:'filename',
            params: {
                'token': <%- JSON.stringify(token) %>,
                'path':"/images/feed/"
            }
        }
    })
```

[image]

Comment: This was originally requested in https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/issues/1325. Follow the linked pull request at the end of that issue for updates.

Comment: Big Thanks! Its working fine now, they should commit this change really.

Comment: what is working now? you mean the code from that branch? and "they" is "me". It's an in-progress release, currently available as v5.16.0-alpha.2 on npm.

Comment: ahhhh, i just only realise man, haha, thanks anyway. ya, the optional return success parameter i mean. ;) Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was originally requested in github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/issues/1325. Follow the linked pull request at the end of that issue for updates. – Ray Nicholus 20 hours ago